# PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. while calculation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Got warning as below: (python3.11.1, pandas:1.5.3)
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

And my code is as below:
df[i] = df[f'{i}_a'].subtract(df[f'{i}_b'])

Please help me know how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: The error message already indicates what you can do when building the frame (concat if you were doing a lot of inserts), and what to do to fix this for an existing frame (df.copy()). The first answer that we would give is already in those instructions. Have you tried those yet? if not, why not? If yes, can you tell us what issues you ran into, so we can give an answer that's actually relevant for your use case?

Comment: how to use concat to do df[i] =df[f'{i}_a'].subtract(df[f'{i}_b'])?

Comment: for that case, use `df = df.copy()` at the end, *as the error message also suggests*